# letter class with header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, letters

When I create a letter using the standard `letter` class, and try to create header using `fancyhdr` package, the header never displays even after using `\thispagestyle{fancy}`. I do not like to use KOMA-Script. Would someone like to help me out?
Regards
VB

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `letter` document class uses two different page styles for the first page depending on whether `\address` is used or not: `firstpage` if it is not used, and `empty`, otherwise. You can redefine the `plain` page style for pages other than the first, and then `\let` those other two styles to be `plain`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Joe Smith -- Senior Manager}
\fancyfoot[C]{\scshape
  100 Main Street. \\ 
  Chicago, IL 60610 \\
  \Email~{\normalfont\ttfamily www.tex.stackexchange.com} \\
  \Telefon~555-345678  \\
  \Mobilefone~3123127854
  }
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@plain
\makeatother

\address{Joe Smith \\ 100 Main Street. \\ Chicago, IL 60610}

\begin{document}%

\begin{letter}{Department  \\ University of X\\ City, State Area Code}%

\opening{Dear Some Name,}

\lipsum


\vfill

Sincerely,

\vfill

Joe Smith

Ph.D. Candidate

Department 

University 
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A close-up to the header:

[image]

A close-up to the footer:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. How can we make this header more attractive with name and designation as central header. And address as a footer in caps and using symbols for phone and email.

Comment: @user34083 please see my updated answer.

Comment: Will adding logo as watermark make it look better? I changed it a little bit. \fancyhead[C]{{\LARGE Joe Smith}\\ Senior Manager}

Comment: @user34083 about the logo, I wouldn't know; it is *your* letter format not mine :-)

Comment: @user34083 also, I see your edit was rejected by other users. Please only make essential edits to posts. You can make any minor changes in your actual document, but they were most probably considered not essential for my answer.