# Headers not showing in Arabic letter

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fancyhdr, polyglossia, arabic

I am trying to create a letter template in Arabic for my business. I am trying to include headers and footers using the `fancyhdr` package. However, whenever I try to compile the document it shows the content without headers. Here is the code and the resulting document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{plain}
\rhead{تعاونية }
\lhead{الرئيس: }

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@plain
\makeatother



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian,hijricorrection=1,locale=morocco]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\address{}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ألي السيد}
\opening{\textbf{الموضوع: فلاحي.}
\\ \\
\\ سلام تام بوجود مولانا الإمام:}


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130272/54817